# Is it possible to get the assigned template type outside the templated class?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do

```
template <typename T>
class myClass {};

auto p = new myClass<int32_t>;
int TSizeOfP = sizeof(??);
```

So I want to get the T which I set to int32_t outside myClass from the object pointer.

Obviously I know what I set it to so I could just do = sizeof(int32_t) but I want to be able to declare the type just once and not have to go over all the places where i wrote sizeof(int32_t) if I decide to change the type.

I could also do something like #define pType int32_t or using statement or whatever but if there is a way to do it without the extra line, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a template class with partial specialization, and a helper function to accomplish it.

```
template <typename T>
struct template_parameter_type {
};
template <typename T, template <typename> class C>
struct template_parameter_type<C<T>> {
    typedef T type;
};
template <typename T>
auto get_size(T*) {
    return sizeof(typename template_parameter_type<T>::type);
}
```

then

```
auto p = new myClass<int32_t>;
int TSizeOfP = get_size(p);
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/LEZN26804)

Comment: That's clever. A non-intrusive way of solving the problem.

Comment: You can get rid of the final template function by adding `static constexpr auto size = sizeof(T);` to the `template_parameter_type` specialization, turning it into a metafunction.

Answer (score 3):

What about making the size a member?

```
template <typename T>
class myClass
{
    typedef T type;
    static constexpr std::size_t TypeSize = sizeof(T);
};

//...

std::size_t TSizeofP = p->TypeSize;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <template<typename> class TT, typename T> 
int typesizeof(TT<T>*& o) {
    return sizeof(T);
}

template <typename T>
class myClass {};

int main() {


    auto p = new myClass<int32_t>;
    cout << typesizeof(p);
    return 0;
}
```

A little more compact nested structs.